# How to use character literals in GNU GAS to replace numbers?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

For example, I'd like to write something like `'a'` instead of `0x61` like I can in C.

The manual mentions them at: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Chars.html but without an example I'm not sure I understood.

Comment: If anyone can explain the downvote, let me know so I can learn and improve the information ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/* Immediate. Without the `$`, does a memory access, and segfaults! */
mov $'a, %al
/* al == 0x61 */

/* Memory. */
mov c, %al
/* al == 0x62 */

c: .byte 'b

/* Space character works. */
mov $' , %al
/* al == 0x20 */

/* Backslash escapes work. */
mov $'\n , %al
/* al == 0x0A */
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/23d8f703fdbeb597db4b103c85fb23eb380d50a9/userland/arch/x86_64/char_literals.S).

There was actually an example at: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/Characters.html :

```
.byte  74, 0112, 092, 0x4A, 0X4a, 'J, '\J # All the same value.
```

I dislike this syntax for the following reasons:

- does not play nicely with the C preprocessor: `MACRO($'a)` fails because cpp treats `'` like a char literal.
- may generate trailing whitespace as `$'`, which is hard to observe
- not C-like

Comment: A closing `'` is optional, you don't *have* to omit it.  (I hadn't realized you even *could* omit it).  `mov $'a', %al` assembles just fine, and is what I'd normally use.

Comment: But unfortunately `mov $'abcd', %eax` is not accepted the way NASM does.  The `ab` part looks to GAS like a backwards ref to label `97`, like `1b` but with the ASCII code for `a`.  So you get weird error messages.