# Can an immediate 32 bit value be written as a four character constant in the GNU assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, constants, gnu-assembler

On a x86 (32 bit) environment, I can push a 32 bit value onto the stack (intel syntax):

```
push 0x576f7264
```

This 32 bit value is the hexadecimal representation of the (not null terminated) string `Word`. I am wondering if there is a way in GNU assembler to write a 32 bit constant as a four character string, so that I can write the following instruction instead:

```
push 'Word'
```

Comment: [How to use character literals in GNU GAS to replace numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33246811/995714#comment100010685_33246812)